# CSS Background property not showing on iOS devices

Tags: css

How to get CSS background property to display on iOS devices?
I have probably read everything what's available over the internet and nothing helps.
I don't have fixed background because many posts are suggesting to remove `position:fixed;`, my position is set to relative as I have an white overlay here, but even if overlay and position is removed the background is still not visible. I have also tried just `background` property but still the same.

```
.services {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(https://exp-theme.local/wp-content/themes/exp-theme/img/brick-wall-mobile.jpg);
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.key-services:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: .95;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Background is properly displayed on every device apart of iOS.
Do I'm missing something here?
I was designing this page mostly using Chrome Dev Tools but everything was fine there, just real device test shows what's really going on.
Every other background inserted by HTML is showing perfectly.

Comment: Don't know if it helps but this is what I found:
iOS Safari has buggy behavior with background-size: cover; + background-attachment: fixed;
iOS Safari has buggy behavior with background-size: cover; on a page's body.

Comment: @Laisender thanks! Yes, but there must be the way, because I have studied so many websites where the background is set by CSS and using exactly the same code as mine all is working there, so I'm unable to understand this. Many developers are using only CSS to insert the background for the container and they seams to have no problem with this :(

Comment: If you don't use this extensively, you could consider solving it by using a absolute positioned img inside your container that has an `inset: 0; object-fit: cover;` on it so it simulates a background image.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work either, just tried right now :(

Comment: I can write you a small demo.. Wait a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest solution to the problem but here you go, you can use a image as background that will work in safari.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -999;
  inset: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/800/800" />

  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <button>Click me</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and creating this, but you inserted the image using HTML not CSS, this way it works I said that in my first post. When the image is inserted by the `background` or `background-image` CSS property it is not working.

Comment: yeah this is what I meant. I am not aware of a fix for Safari and this bug..

Comment: hmm... I'm sure there must be something as like I've said before I see professional agencies building their WP custom sites using `background` property without any issues. Well maybe they use some sort of JS walk around I don't know but I clearly see images inserted by `background` property in their code.

Answer (score 0):

So this won't work?

```css
.wrapper{
position: relative;
margin: auto;
width: 90%;
background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/800/800');
background-position: center center;
padding: 2rem;
}
.wrapper::before{
content: "";
position: absolute;
inset: 0;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.wrapper:hover::before{
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <button>Click me</button>

</div>
```